# Was Professor Calculus really deaf?

Tags: tintin

Because in various instances I feel he is only “acting deaf”.

Comment: Are there any rather blatant examples of this?

Answer (score 11):

With the exception of the 1957 TV series, in which he is [portrayed as having perfect hearing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFBlZThNaCQ&feature=youtu.be&t=181) Professor Calculus is almost always shown to be **partially deaf in both ears**.

In the original comics (and in the [1991 TV Series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xb5FM67n9Bs&feature=youtu.be&t=622)) he does display the ability to hear with pretty much perfect clarity in [Destination Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destination_Moon_(comics)) (and its sequel), but only when using an ear trumpet or a hearing aid, both of which he dislikes because they're "*meant for deaf people*".

[image]

[image]

Very occasionally he'll hear something accurately, but typically only it's [funnier to have him hear it than not](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfFunny), like this panel from [Flight 714 to Sydney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_714_to_Sydney)

[image]

Comment: FWIW I seem to remember him not being apparently deaf in the the _Golden Fleece_ movie, then again all I really remember from Calculus in that is "it's gold! It's gold...!" :-) *(eh, now I know what I'll be watching this weekend)*

Comment: @Jenayah - He only appears in two scenes in that movie, once at the start where he's just been in an explosion and then at the end where he doesn't have any interacting dialogue. In the scene at the start he's cupping his ear when he speaks to Haddock.

Comment: Funny fact, ear-trumpet is made from ebonite.